# question in C :pointer:|warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

Tags: c

```
void remplacer(char *s, char *w1, char *w2)
{
    int i;
    char aux;

    while (i < strlen(s) - strlen(w1) + 1)
    {
        if (!(strncmp(s + i, w1, strlen(w1))))
        {
            strcpy(aux, s + i + strlen(w1));
            strcpy(s + i, w2);
            strcat(s, aux);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I find a problem with this code I'm a beginner in C help me please this the error :warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

Comment: that's not gonna work - aux is a char.  It holds one character.  You need an array to copy strings around

Comment: You have more problems than that. The `i` variable is uninitialised. What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: If you want to replace one word (`w1`) with another (`w2`) consider using `strstr` to find `w1`. You would need to make that the first step: use the non-`NULL` pointer obtained and go from there. Of course one danger is if `w2` is longer than `w1` there can be buffer overflow. Your function doesn't know the available buffer size.

Comment: There's also an unsigned overflow problem if `w1` is longer than `s`.

Comment: the function must replace in a string s the sequence w1 by w2